# What does mapping in yml file means?

Tags: kubernetes

I am not sure what mapping in YAMl file means, can someone advise what does mapping in YAML
 file means?

Comment: It would really help if you could give an example to clarify the question. Can you point to a file with mapping and the relevant documentation that you read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML is a very simple, text/human-readable annotation format that can be used to store data.
YAML keeps data stored as a map containing keys and values associated to those keys. This map is in no particular order, so you can reorder it at will. Each pair is in the format KEY: VALUE
When the value is a text string enclose the value with quotes. Some examples below:

```
KEY1: 'HELLO'
HOST_NUMBER: 1
```